# Не получается задать условие в кнопке CheckButton. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys, random
from maket import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Исторические личности")
        self.NameOfPerson()
        self.Head()
        self.Nose()
        self.Chin()
#Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.checkButton.clicked.connect(self.CheckButton) #Кнопка проверки
        self.ui.nexthead.clicked.connect(self.nexthead) #Кнопка"ГоловаВперёд"
        self.ui.backhead.clicked.connect(self.backhead) #Кнопка"ГоловаНазад"
        self.ui.nextnose.clicked.connect(self.nextnose) #Кнопка"НосВперёд"
        self.ui.backnose.clicked.connect(self.backnose) #Кнопка"НосНазад"
        self.ui.nextchin.clicked.connect(self.nextchin) #Кнопка"ПодбородокВперёд"
        self.ui.backchin.clicked.connect(self.backchin) #Кнопка"ПодбородокНазад"
#Заголовок(Выводится Имя Исторической личности)
    def NameOfPerson(self):
        # Здесь все возможные имена Исторических людей.
        namesofperson = []
        namesofperson.append("Ярослав Мудрый")
        namesofperson.append("Николай II")
        namesofperson.append("Екатерина I")
        namesofperson.append("Иван IV")
        namesofperson.append("Александр I")
        namesofperson.append("Пётр I")
        namesofperson.append("Александр II")
        namesofperson.append("Александр III")
        namesofperson.append("Владимир Ильич Ленин")
        namesofperson.append("Иосиф Сталин")
        self.ui.nameofperson.setText(namesofperson[0])
#Блок с Собранием Лба
    def Head(self):
        # Здесь все возможные лбы Исторических людей
        head = []
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head0.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head1.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head2.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head3.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head4.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head5.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head6.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head7.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head8.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head9.png'))
        self.ui.head.setPixmap(head[0])
#Блок с Собиранием Носа
    def Nose(self):
        # Здесь все возможные носы Исторических людей
        nose = []
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose0.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose1.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose2.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose3.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose4.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose5.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose6.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose7.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose8.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose9.png'))
        self.ui.nose.setPixmap(nose[0])
#Блок с Собиранием Подбородка
    def Chin(self):
        # Здесь все возможные подбородки Исторических людей
        chin = []
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin0.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin1.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin2.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin3.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin4.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin5.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin6.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin7.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin8.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin9.png'))
        self.ui.chin.setPixmap(chin[0])

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
# при нажатии на кнопку
    def CheckButton(self):
       if self.ui.nameofperson == "Ярослав Мудрый" and self.ui.head == "images\head\head0.png" and self.ui.nose == "images\mnose\mnose0.png"  and self.ui.chin == "images\chin\chin0.png":
            print("Правильно")
       else:
            print("Не правильно попробуй ещё раз!")
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдГолова"
    def nexthead(self):
        pass
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадГолова"
    def backhead(self):
        pass
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдНос"
    def nextnose(self):
        pass
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадНос"
    def backnose(self):
        pass
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдПодбородок"
    def nextchin(self):
        pass
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадПодбородок"
    def backchin(self):
        pass



if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Знакомый попросил сделать программу, человек по кускам лба,носа и рта будет собирать известную историческую личность, которая написана сверху

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Дело в том, что когда картинка собрана правильно и вверху написано "Ярослав мудрый". В условии пишет что: "Не правильно"

Comment: Хм, ну ладно. А какое именно условие в if не сработало проверили? Выведите части условия как `print(self.ui.nameofperson == "Ярослав Мудрый")` `print(self.ui.head == "images\head\head0.png")` и т.д.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали. Программа запускается компилятор ничего не пишет

Comment: По-моему Вы сравниваете разные типы данных. Вот например: "images\head\head0.png" - это строка, а что такое - self.ui.head ?

Comment: @МаксимХалин, ну не компилятор, а интерпретатор. А раз не пишет, то не дошло до места с print'ом.